# Error Creating .deb File of AMD Catalyst Driver

Tags: 12.04, ati, fglrx, catalyst

I was following the steps to install AMD Catalyst Driver from [wiki.cchtml.com](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide).

While I was creating the .deb file the following error occured--

```
$ sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
Created directory fglrx-install.jItiVW
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-9.012....................................................................................
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Generating package: Ubuntu/precise
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
Cleaning in directory .
# refresh copyright file
cat debian/copyright_stub_0 > debian/copyright
cat usr/share/doc/fglrx/LICENSE.TXT >> debian/copyright
cat debian/copyright_stub_1 >> debian/copyright
# remove any file generated from a template
for file in *.in; do \
    # strip only the last .in from the name \
    filename=`echo $file | sed -e "s|.in||"` \
    rm -f ; \
done
dh clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:9.012-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by AMD: Advanced Micro Devices. <http://ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.CRghMG
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
 debian/rules build
#Create important strings
for i in 10fglrx \
         dkms.conf \
         fglrx.install \
         fglrx-dev.install \
         fglrx-dev.links \
         fglrx-amdcccle.install \
         fglrx.grub-gfxpayload \
         fglrx.dirs \
         fglrx.links \
         fglrx.postinst \
         fglrx.postrm \
         fglrx.preinst \
         fglrx.prerm \
         overrides/fglrx; do \
    sed -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR#|usr/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#LIBDIR32#|usr/lib32|g" \
        -e "s|#BINDIR#|usr/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#SYSCONFDIR#|etc|g" \
        -e "s|#MANDIR#|usr/share/man/man1|g" \
        -e "s|#LDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPRIORITY#|1000|g" \
        -e "s|#PXALTPRIORITY#|900|g" \
        -e "s|#AUTOSTARTDIR#|etc/xdg/autostart|g" \
        -e "s|#DATADIR#|usr/share|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDESKDIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDATADIR#|usr/share/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGCONFIGDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGBINDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/bin|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGDRIVERSDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTRA#|usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGEXTENSIONDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg|g" \
        -e "s|#XORGEXTENSIONSDIR#|usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERNAME#|fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERDEVNAME#|fglrx-dev|g" \
        -e "s|#DRIVERSRCNAME#||g" \
        -e "s|#INCLUDEDIR#|usr/include|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGLIBCONFDIR#|lib/fglrx|g" \
        -e "s|#GRUBBLKLISTDIR#|usr/share/grub-gfxpayload-lists/blacklist|g" \
        -e "s|#PKGXMODDIR#|usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXXMODDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/xorg/modules|g" \
        -e "s|#PXDIRNAME#|pxpress|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR#|usr/lib/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLIBDIR32#|usr/lib32/pxpress/lib|g" \
        -e "s|#PXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#ALTPXLDSOCONF#|usr/lib/pxpress/alt_ld.so.conf|g" \
        -e "s|#CVERSION#|9.012|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCXARCH#|xpic|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCARCH#|x86|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCOTHERARCH#|x86_64|g" \
        -e "s|#SRCLIBDIR#|lib|g" \
        -e "s|#DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH#|i386-linux-gnu|g" \
        -e "s|#OTHER_ARCH#|x86_64-linux-gnu|g" \
        debian/$i.in > debian/$i;      \
done
# remove exec bit on everything
find arch \
    etc \
    lib \
    module \
    usr \
    xpic     -type f | xargs chmod -x
find: `module': No such file or directory
# set executable on user apps
find arch/x86/usr/sbin \
    arch/x86/usr/X11R6/bin \
    usr/sbin/ -type f | xargs chmod a+x
# set exec bit on scripts
find lib etc debian -name "*.sh" -type f | xargs chmod +x
# set the permissions on the pxpress scripts
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
   dh_auto_test
dh build
 debian/rules binary
# refresh copyright file
cat debian/copyright_stub_0 > debian/copyright
cat usr/share/doc/fglrx/LICENSE.TXT >> debian/copyright
cat debian/copyright_stub_1 >> debian/copyright
#Steps that we can't easily represent in debhelper files or .in files yet
# Remove any libraries that may be caught by shell expansion
find . -name libGLE* | xargs rm -f
find . -name libEGL* | xargs rm -f
dh_installdirs -pfglrx
# Install the QT libraries
dh_install -pfglrx "arch/x86_64/usr/share/ati/lib" "usr/share/ati"
cp: cannot stat `debian/tmp/arch/x86_64/usr/share/ati/lib': No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/arch/x86_64/usr/share/ati/lib debian/fglrx/usr/share/ati/ returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.jItiVW
```

Please help me.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 i386 .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a terrible experience with this "**amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run**" under Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit last week. After "successful" installation and reboot, my computer got stuck at the stage of starting X. Luckily I had made a **backup** of my Ubuntu partition with **Clonezilla**. If you're lucky, it might work under Ubuntu 12.04, but just in case I recommend making a backup first. Also perhaps it might be a better idea to install those proprietary drivers from Ubuntu repositories (start **Software Sources** > **Additional Drivers**). They gave me a functioning desktop at least, although neither Unity nor Compiz was functioning ;-)

So, I found the only working solution to control this fancy Hybrid Graphics Card here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics
- http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com

As a result, after checking that my system has got **vga_switcheroo** support, I've become content with automatically **turning the discreet graphics on and off** when I switch between **AC and Battery power supply** by simply adding a small executable script file named **11_hybrid_graphics_switch** into the folder **/etc/pm/power.d** with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
if on_ac_power; then
    echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch &
else
    echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch &
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's my oversight ;-) Apparently this file is also a hybrid one ;-)

Comment: [1] Where is the 32 bit version? It seems the "amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run" contains both 32bit(x86) and 64bit(x86_64).  [2] I'm currently using driver from Xorg Xswat(unable to switch between Intel and AMD using [Roberto Martinez's](http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com/) method), but I would love to install ATI's driver..  [3] When I try to install AMD's fglrx driver from "Additional Driver", it does not work for me and it becomes Unity 2D again.

Comment: [2] I simply reverted to Ubuntu's default open source drivers after the other 2 methods performed worse. I don't know if it's Xorg Xswat. But perhaps you should first check if your machine has vga_switcheroo support, etc. as explained in ubuntu help web page above, and try those Echo commands in root terminal. [3] You're lucky with this method, I couldn't even get a 2D Unity ;-)

Comment: [2] yes my machine (kernel) do support vga_switcheroo (tested as described in [Ubuntu help documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) and I've tried th echo command.  [3] ya may be. but it does help me getting the proper AMD driver.

Comment: I understand, of course, you don't have to surrender so quickly like me ;-) But I think you might also like to check why you can't get, for instance, the command **echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch** work in **Root Terminal** (to turn off the discreet graphics to save power when on battery) if you also decide to be content with this solution until they offer a smoothly running driver.

Comment: actually my discrete graphics card is switched off after installing xorg driver. the thing is i can't switch it on. for playing games i need to switch it on but alas i'm undone.

Comment: for your script can i get some details or references please? and why it's named with 11? and with this script should i still have to have echo OFF in rc.local?

Comment: My main reference was **https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics** and I merely transplanted the 2 basic commands there into another simple script performing this or that action depending on whether the computer is "on_ac_power" or not. I just added 11 before the name arbitrarily so as to follow the naming convention in such system folders to run the scripts there in a certain sequence. Perhaps there might be cases where this number might need to be changed so as to run this script a little earlier or later than others in that "power.daemon folder".