# drivers for Radeon HD 7670 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I have AMD Radeon HD 7670M graphic card. I want to know if theres any graphic driver present for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Will Ubuntu 12.04 support this GPU on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I've got **AMD Radeon HD 7450M** graphics card, and it worked perfectly well under **Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit)**. The same should probably apply to your card as well, which you can test by booting the said computer with a live CD/DVD/USB.

The only problem was the too much **power consumption** as it was actually a **Hybrid Graphics** card with an "Integrated" Intel graphics controller and a "Discreet" AMD/ATI one. I finally figured out how to turn off the latter when the computer is running on battery power. See: [Error Creating .deb File of AMD Catalyst Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269089/error-creating-deb-file-of-amd-catalyst-driver/269096#269096)