# Video card high temperature on HP ProBook 4530s-LH306EA

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, amd-graphics

My notebook is HP ProBook 4530s-LH306EA. I have two video cards discrete(AMD Radeon HD 6490M) and integrated.

Today I have installed Ubuntu 12.10, and meet the problem that my computer become very hot (Jupiter shows from 75-85 degrees). I have understood that the problem in video card, so I have tried to switch off discrete using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics
But I don't know how to switch it forever, because after computer restarts discrete is switched on.

And I cannot understand why there is so big problem with this video cards? On windows exists program, that knows which of this two video cards to use.

**PS** I have missed step with backup and start installing, but then occur error: "One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver. Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools. Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended. See `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` for more details"

In log file is written:

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
```

**PSS** I have run with --force option and get:

```
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
fglrx installation is being forced. Installation will proceed without the required tools on the system.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.
Unloading radeon module...
ERROR: Module radeon is in use
Unloading drm module...
ERROR: Module drm is in use by radeon,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
[Message] Kernel Module : Trying to install a precompiled kernel module.
[Message] Kernel Module : Precompiled kernel module version mismatched.
[Error] Kernel Module : Kernel module build environment not found - please consult readme.
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot install/use **AMD Catalyst Driver** (like me) either from Ubuntu repositories or manually from their website, you can automatically turn the discreet graphics on and off when you switch between AC and Battery power supply by simply adding a small executable script file named **11_hybrid_graphics_switch** into the folder **/etc/pm/power.d** with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
if on_ac_power; then
    echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch &
else
    echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch &
fi
exit 0
```

For more info, see my answer at: [Error Creating .deb File of AMD Catalyst Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269089/error-creating-deb-file-of-amd-catalyst-driver/269096#269096)

Comment: nice solution. but I would prefer to fully disable discrete card. Will this script work if in third line I write echo OFF? And what will happen when I start computer?

Comment: If you are sure about it, replacing "ON" with "OFF" in the 3rd line should give the result you want, but I think in that case there should be a simpler way of doing it, e.g. simply adding the 5th line in one of the startup scripts, e.g. **rc.local**?

Comment: ok, thank you for the help. How do you thing this bug with drivers will be solved in future?

Comment: I personally don't know. It seems the proprietary drivers don't work well under Ubuntu 12.10. Perhaps the card manufacturers can develop their Linux driver better in the course of time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use AMD Catalyst Driver. You can switch between AMD Graphics or Integrated graphics graphically. This is the link for the tutorial:  [BinaryDriverHowto/ATI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI). Read section 3.2, hope that help you.

Comment: I have tried to install it, but at the first step occur errors, there is no file /etc/X11/xorg.conf